# Camelot: Using "table_regions" argument returns "too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

Tags: python, python-camelot

I'm trying to extract tabular data from pdf using Camelot. When using the argument "table_regions" I get and error "too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('BOA1.pdf',flavor="stream",pages="3",table_regions=['1,1,1,1'])
```

resulted in:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-681440b4cbbd> in <module>()
----> 1 tables = camelot.read_pdf('BOA1.pdf',flavor="stream",pages="3-20",table_regions=['1,1,1,1'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py in read_pdf(filepath, pages, password, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    104         kwargs = remove_extra(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
    105         tables = p.parse(flavor=flavor, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,
--> 106                          layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    107         return tables

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py in parse(self, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    160             for p in pages:
    161                 t = parser.extract_tables(p, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,
--> 162                                           layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs)
    163                 tables.extend(t)
    164         return TableList(tables)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\stream.py in extract_tables(self, filename, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs)
    417             return []
    418 
--> 419         self._generate_table_bbox()
    420 
    421         _tables = []

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\stream.py in _generate_table_bbox(self)
    287                 hor_text = []
    288                 for region in self.table_regions:
--> 289                     x1, y1, x2, y2 = region
    290                     region_text = text_in_bbox((x1, y2, x2, y1), self.horizontal_text)
    291                     hor_text.extend(region_text)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug.
They are going to fix it.

See https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot/issues/312

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the fact that table_region = [1, 1,1 ,1] represents a point and not an area.